# Error constantly thrown by JBoss

Tags: jboss

```
2011-06-02 17:27:01,990 ERROR [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint] Socket error caused by remote host /a.b.c.d

java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketSetOption(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.setOption(PlainSocketImpl.java:264)
    at java.net.Socket.setTcpNoDelay(Socket.java:839)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.setSocketOptions(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:503)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.MasterSlaveWorkerThread.run(MasterSlaveWorkerThread.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

Comment: would help if you add some more info.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an error in your JVM.  If so, its been fixed in the latest VMs.

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6378870

What version of Java are you using and on what platform?

Can you provide more info on the issue?